# Hide/Show elements on "back" (Mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build my first responsive website, but I need the "back" button on the mobile devices to not go back on the history, but to do an action for me.
So, I have this:

HTML:

```
<div id='button1'></div>
<div id='button2'style='display: none;'></div>
```

JS:

```
$('#button1').click(function(){
  $('#button1').css('display', 'none');
  $('#button2').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

I need the "back button" to do the reverse of this, that is:

```
$('#button2').click(function(){
  $('#button2').css('display', 'none');
  $('#button1').css('display', 'inline-block');
});
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `window` history stack, you can choose to do whatever action you want to do on the ***back action***, as long as the previous page in the history stack is a page ***on your domain***.

This is achieved using [*`pushState()`* /  *`popState()`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

More importantly the event `popstate`.

#### Example:

```js
window.onpopstate = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  // DO some other action besides going back
  return false
}
```

#### Note:

A recommended approach to always be able to leverage the back action, is to check the `history` stack, and if there are not enough states to pop on, simply `push` a few on, so you can always catch the ***back event***. Something like this:

```
while (window.history.length < 5) {
  history.pushState({foo:1}, "Dummy poppable page", window.location.path)
}
```

Comment: And thus, a new spammer/browser hijacker was born

Comment: I take no responsibility for how this code is used :P

Comment: Thank you. That's exactly what I needed, I simple just put `history.pushState` inside the `.click` function, so it will create a dummy page only when the user click on the button.